# “I can speak three languages”

Tags: modal-verb

I want to say the following in German:

> I can speak three languages.

I am wondering if what I came up with is correct:

> Ich kann drei Sprachen sprechen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *ich kann drei Sprachen sprechen* is correct. *Ich spreche drei Sprachen*, too.